# Usage of oracle function sys connect by path

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

We have a problem that it seens not supported in oracle 10g what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Post the query - [per the 10g documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions149.htm):

> ...[it's] valid only in hierarchical queries.

[Supporting asktom link](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:907278700346567560) about using `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` with 10gR2...